# Will an adapter with an EMF AF Confirm chip work with my vintage lens?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-adapter, canon-6d, vintage

Just bought my first vintage lens on eBay, the the Helios 44-2 58mm f/2 and now I am looking for an adapter for it to mount it on my Canon 6D.  I noticed that the EMF M42 adapters can be had with and without AF confirmation chip.  Will this particular lens actually transmit any data to my camera? Will I get a focus confirmation? I think not, but I am new to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The EMF chip, when correctly positioned and glued to an adapter ring will perform autofocus confirmation and communicate EXIF lens information (focal length, max. aperture, and even the aperture setting used--*if* you follow the correct steps while shooting) on a digital Canon EOS body (I've used them on an XT, 50D, and 5DMkII).  The adapter ring and the lens it's attached to don't really affect this function.  The quality/fit of the adapter ring, however, is independent of the chip. The chip is sold separately from the rings, and can be glued on by anyone.

You may also want to look at [the manual for the EMF chip](http://whitemetal.com/canon/emf_chip/EMF%20AF%20Confirm%20Chip%20For%20M42%20Lens%20To%20Canon.pdf).

In my experience, however, AF confirmation is not as useful at nailing focus with very thin DoF on a fast lens as the Canon "matte precision" focus screens (if your camera body allows for the use of one), or liveview with 10x magnification or focus peaking & Magic Zoom a la [Magic Lantern](http://magiclantern.fm/).