# Is there a way to add adapted vintage lens EXIF information to my files manually?

Tags: dslr, metadata, lens-adapter, old-lenses

I have a number of vintage lenses and since I am mounting them on a digital camera the lens information isn't available.

Strangely, my photos have the information of the last digital lens that I used on my camera (a Canon 60D). This is kind of annoying as I sometimes browse my photos and it's giving me the wrong information, similarly when people look at those photos they get wrong info.

How do I set the lens info manually, either in camera or with an application? How do I remove the wrong lens info?

Comment: You haven't indicated what kind of lens, or adapter you use. In case it's an M42 adapter [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43531/9161) might be relevant or even a duplicate.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke, it's actually fine whether or not the adapter/lens is M42. I've retitled the older question to genericize for any adapter with an EMF chip glued to it. :) Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke how can it be the same question as mine while it's talking about the differences between AF chips and I'm asking how to set/reset this info. The person who asked that, seems to know about this chip that I had no idea until now

Comment: It's not exactly the same question (and I haven't voted to close either), but your question seemed to be looking for a similar thing from a different angle.

Comment: @xbmono, when we say something's a duplicate around here, we often mean that the question will have duplicate *answers*, even though the questions can be phrased very differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get some lens EXIF information, such as the focal length of the lens, is to find a chip for your adapter ring that fakes being a Canon EF lens chip. These can be programmed to push out EXIF information, as well as perform AF confirmation, and hold AF adjustment settings. I used to use the EMF chips back when I shot Canon with adapted lenses, because you could, iirc, also program it to include the actual aperture setting you were using at the time.

See: [Will an adapter with an EMF AF Confirm chip work with my vintage lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/63672)

But you can also add or edit the lens EXIF information after the fact using the command-line [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) or its library, or any of the GUIs that use them. Because I'm a Lightroom user, the donationware [LensTagger plugin](https://www.lenstagger.com/) is my tool of choice, because it can save off information for a specific lens (and film) combo and then reload it, so if you use a number of different adapted lenses, you aren't having to refill in all the fields over and over. But it's a bit of the PITA, as you have to also make sure to get Lightroom to update the database after you've written to the files' EXIF.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I set the lens info manually, either in camera or with an application? How do I remove the wrong lens info?

If you are willing to do it after the fact, any of the leading EXIF info editors are capable of doing this.

[ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) is probably the most widely recognized and used application for editing pretty much any field in the EXIF info for an image file.

For more, please see:
[Software for editing EXIF data](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3268/15871)
[Are there GIMP plugins that allow one to view and edit EXIF data?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1512/15871)
[Is there a software that make it possible to edit all exif values and add new paramerers?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3633/15871)
[Adding data to an EXIF file](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1177/15871)